# How to create a white noise signal in Python, and filter the noise signal with bandpass filter?

Tags: python, audio, signals, noise, pyaudio

I'm doing a project about speech processing. I wonder how to create a white noise signal in Python, and filter the noise signal with bandpass filter?

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal

CHUNK = 64 #the block size
Q = 50

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = pa.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                            channels=1,
                            rate=44100,
                            output=True)
while True:
    noise = np.random.uniform(-1,1,CHUNK)
    b,a = signal.iirfilter(1,[2*500*(1-1/(2*Q))/44100,2*500*(1+1/(2*Q))/44100])
    output = signal.lfilter(b,a,noise)
    output.astype(np.float32)
    output = output.tobytes()
    stream.write(output)
```

Is the code right? And what is the difference between `signal.iirfilter` and `signal.butter`?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this a signal processing question or a coding question?  You might want to search/ask over at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/.  white noise == random amplitude/period..??

Comment: It is a code question. I want to create Python code to generate a white noise signal and filter it.

Comment: How do you define white noise and what type of filter do you want to apply?  Does the solution you provided give the desired result? If not what is wrong with it?  What is the expected result?  Can you provide a minimal example of the input?  Please read [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Great Python question for StackOverflow. The white noise def is on Wikipedia. Here is an example of white noise wav file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k7LKEYzzIg6l6nbil4b5oVMyy9gFlWcF/view?usp=sharing